# Getting data from laravel relation on Foreign Key

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, entity-relationship, laravel-artisan

I have to SQL tables: `users` and `roles`; The user table consists of an `id (PRIMARY)`, `email`, `password` and a `role_id (INDEX)` column. The role table consists of an `id (PRIMARY)` and a `name` column. A user can only have a single role (Admin or User).

This is how my laravel Models look like:

```
// User Model
public function role()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Role::class);
}

// Role model
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

What i want is, when i get the information of a user, i want to get the corresponding role of that user.

When i place this code in the Artisan Tinker:

```
// Get user with id=2
App\User::find(2)->role;
```

This seems logical to me `"Find the role belonging to the user with id 2"`

But it is throwing this error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'roles.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `roles` where `roles`.`user_id` = 2 and `roles`.`user_id` is not null limit 1)'
```

How Can i get the role of a User without calling it from the Role model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a `role_id` on `users` table, you should have `belongsTo(Role::class)` on `User` model:

```
// User Model
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```

And `hasMany(User::class)` on role model:

```
// Role model
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

Comment: I had already tried this one. But it threw the same error. Seems i had to restart te Arisan Tinker for it to notice the changes.

Comment: Yes, if you're trying with tinker, you have to restart it whenever you make changes to your code. Annoying, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there should be belongsToMany instead of belongsTo. This should fix the problem. Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

> Unknown column 'roles.user_id'

This is the error. Your roles table should have `user_id` column.